Gremlin Console - Connecting to Amazon Neptune with Sig4 signing
I need to connect to Amazon Neptune using Gremlim console. 
Tried all steps for setup and signing configuration but following error occurs when connecting to Neptune.
Steps performed:

Install JDK
sudo amazon-linux-extras install java-openjdk11


Install Gremlin Console
wget https://archive.apache.org/dist/tinkerpop/3.4.10/apache-tinkerpop-gremlin-console-3.4.10-bin.zip

unzip apache-tinkerpop-gremlin-console-3.4.10-bin.zip

cd apache-tinkerpop-gremlin-console-3.4.10


Install AWS signing library: amazon-neptune-gremlin-java-sigv4
bin\gremlin.sh

         \,,,/
         (o o)
-----oOOo-(3)-oOOo-----
plugin activated: tinkerpop.server
plugin activated: tinkerpop.utilities
plugin activated: tinkerpop.tinkergraph
gremlin> :install com.amazonaws amazon-neptune-sigv4-signer 2.4.0
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.util.DependencyGrabber).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
==>Loaded: [com.amazonaws, amazon-neptune-sigv4-signer, 2.4.0]


Create configuration for Neptune connection: conf/neptune-remote.yaml
hosts: [your-neptune-endpoint]
port: 8182
connectionPool: {
    channelizer: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.SigV4WebSocketChannelizer,
    enableSsl: true
} 
serializer: { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphBinaryMessageSerializerV1,
          config: { serializeResultToString: true }}


Connect (fails)
gremlin> :remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/neptune-remote.yaml
==>Error during 'connect' - The channelizer specified [org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.SigV4WebSocketChannelizer] could not be instantiated - it should be the fully qualified classname of a Channelizer implementation available on the classpath





How do I get this working? Do I need to set classpath?

You need to follow the documentation located here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/iam-auth-connecting-gremlin-console.html

I used the same document (linked in my question) and yet getting error when I try to connect. Does it need to have explicit classpath?

You don't need to set classpath.  It looks like you're skipping steps 3-6 from the document that I linked.  You need to import the two other SigV4 classes into the console and use the cluster builder.

Thanks.
I was following the steps from second part of the documentation, specific to Gremlin Console version below 3.4.11.
I set everything up again (with steps 3-6) and now Neptune returns Forbidden. Will fix the access policy and try again.

Ah, yes.  3.4.10 is fairly old at this point.  There have been a lot of improvements with connection management in the more recent releases that Neptune supports (up to 3.6.5, to this point).

For an optimal developer experience with your Amazon Neptune database you may also want to consider alternative tools that are better integrated (and far more feature-rich) than the default Gremlin Console, particularly when it comes to IAM auth use cases.
The Amazon Neptune team provides Graph Notebook https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/graph-notebooks.html which can be either deployed manually or via Amazon SageMaker
G.V() (https://gdotv.com) is a graph IDE that is fully compatible with Amazon Neptune and offers advanced capabilities, as shown in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/visualization-GV.html. In the interest of disclosure, G.V() is a tool that I maintain.
There's also a list of other available tools listed directly on the Amazon Neptune documentation at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/visualization-tools.html.
